# Powershell - AD Report create a new column with a generic value

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I use this script to query my AD and extract user data.

```
Get-Aduser -filter *  -Properties *| Select-Object -Property SamAccountName,CN,co,ExtensionAttribute10,extensionAttribute11,extensionAttribute12,EmailAddress,whenCreated,Enabled,LastLogonDate,accountexpirationdate, @{Name='parentOU'; Expression={[regex]::match($_.distinguishedname,'(?<=OU=.+?OU=).+?(?=,(OU|DC)=)').Value}},distinguishedname,description  | Sort-Object -Property Name  <#| Where-Object {$_.distinguishedname -like "*regular*"-or $_.distinguishedname -like "*remote*" -or $_.distinguishedname -like "*shopfloor*" -or $_.distinguishedname -like "*brp admin*"  }#> | Export-Csv -append -Delimiter ";" -path $path
```

I would like to take the result of the "enable" column, which is True or False, and create a new column call "suspended" if the result of enable is true the value to put in "suspended" is no. If the result is false, the value to put in "suspended should be "yes"

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new calculated property that is based on the value of the Enabled property.

```
... | Select-Object ... ,Enabled,@{n='Suspended';e={if($_.Enabled){'no'}else{'yes'}}},...
```